# How to delete SQS message in AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environments using PHP SDK

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment setup using SQS. The SQS is posting to a URL, which is an endpoint to a codebase that uses Laravel. From this endpoint, it takes up the message and process the payload. Some of my processes are time-consuming and is taking more than 20 minutes to complete. I am sending back a success response from the endpoint, but as it takes a lot of time to complete the process, most of the time, the messages are going to the inflight mode in SQS. I am trying to make a deleteMessage() call using PHP SDK, but I need to pass `ReceiptHandle` for deleting a message. As per the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html), SQS is not posting `ReceiptHandle` to my application and so I can't make a delete call. The problem with messages in `inFlight` mode is that it will be called again in the next time the and so the process is duplicated.

How can I delete a message once the process is completed ?

My current code is as follows :

```
 $worker->process(
            $request->header('X-Aws-Sqsd-Queue'), $job, [
                'maxTries' => 0,
                'delay' => 0
            ]
        );
        return $this->response([
            'Processed ' . $job->getJobId()
        ]);
```

Where worker is an instance of

```
Illuminate\Queue\Worker;
```

and the `response` function is json encoding the data and respond with `200`

Answer (score 0):

You must have **ReceiptHandle** to delete a message in queue. In core PHP below is the function to read and delete a message in queue.

```
function ReadMessages($client,$queueUrl){
    try {
        $result = $client->receiveMessage(array(
            'AttributeNames' => ['SentTimestamp'],
            'MaxNumberOfMessages' => 1,
            'MessageAttributeNames' => ['All'],
            'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl, // REQUIRED
            'WaitTimeSeconds' => 0,
        ));
        if (count($result->get('Messages')) > 0) {
            var_dump($result->get('Messages')[0]);

            //to delete a message pass the receipt Handle
            $result = $client->deleteMessage([
                'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl, // REQUIRED
                'ReceiptHandle' => $result->get('Messages')[0]['ReceiptHandle'] // REQUIRED
            ]);
            } else {
                echo "No messages in queue. \n";
            }
        }   
    catch (AwsException $e) {
        // output error message if fails
        return 'error';
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Do some workaround so you get a **ReceiptHandle** to delete a message in queue.

Comment: I have tried this. But unfortunately, I am not getting any messages. I am using this to the endpoint to which SQS posts.

Comment: can you clear up the process you have done with code or screenshots